# Android Studio Emulator Proxy isn't working

Tags: android, android-studio, proxy, android-emulator, adb

I am having trouble getting the proxy settings on the Android Studio Emulator to work.

This is a HTTP proxy with Sticky IP and I've tried with both DNS Hostname and IP Hostname and in every case it says This site can't be reached with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I need to get in working global across all apps on the device.
Managed to get the proxy working trough the adb shell command - adb shell settings put global http_proxy 52.7.150.172:31112 but it worked only in the browser. Didn't work across other apps

Attached below are screenshots.

[DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0ESF.png)
[IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVM9l.png)

Comment: Does the proxy perform HTTPS interception? If yes this is the problem. You need to root the emulator and install the proxy root CA certificate as system certificate. user certificates are ignored by most apps (except Chrome). https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-install-system-trusted-ca-android/